# How to write the following group by  and stripping time Linq query?

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-entities, group-by

I have list like this-

```
Id    Date
1     01/03/2011 14:15:23.320
1     01/03/2011 16:15:23.320
1     01/03/2011 18:15:23.320
1     01/04/2011 19:15:23.320
2     01/03/2011 14:15:23.320
2     01/03/2011 15:15:23.320
2     01/03/2011 18:15:23.320
2     01/05/2011 19:15:23.320
2     01/07/2011 20:15:23.320
```

My desired output is -

```
Id    Date
1     01/03/2011
1     01/04/2011 
2     01/03/2011 
2     01/05/2011 
2     01/07/2011
```

So how can I group by on the first list on id and take only the date part and achieve the results above in Linq ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var result = yourList.GroupBy(item => 
    new {Id = item.Id, Date = item.Date.Date});
```

Basically, `DateTime.Date` strips the time information.

To loop through the result, you could do:

```
foreach(var grp in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grp.Key.Id, grp.Key.Date);
}
```

Comment: I get `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities` exception can I get around this ? I am trying to do this all in a query?

Comment: @Misnomer. Ah, linq to entities all of a sudden. Why didn't you say so from the beginning?

Comment: @Misnomer, you can force the records into memory before grouping by adding `AsEnumerable` to your "query". Like `yourList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy....`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to group on the date **and** id, so you want to pull those out into a structure that you can group on.  It's when you create this key structure that you can format the date using the Date property to create the grouping correctly:

```
from item in list
group item by new { item.Id, Date = item.Date.Date } into g
select g
```

At that point, the keys in the grouping returned will give you the list you want.